# Lightning Datatable with wrapperclass

Tags: lightning-datatable, wrapper-class

How can I use my wrapperclass with a lightning:datatable, Is that possible?
At the moment I use

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wl" title="all activities">
```

to display the result.

**CLASS**

```
    public class DokuBox_6 {
    
    public List<Wrapper> wrapperList {get; set;}
    public String currentRecordId {get; set;}
    
    public DokuBox_6() {
        currentRecordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        
        if(wrapperList == null) {
            wrapperList = new List<Wrapper>();
            
            for(Task a: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status from Task where WhoId =: currentRecordId AND Subject LIKE 'E-Mail:%']) {
                wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(a, 'E-Mail'));
            }
            for(Task a: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status from Task where WhoId =: currentRecordId AND (NOT Subject LIKE 'E-Mail:%')]) {
                wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(a, 'Aufgabe'));
            }            
            for(Event b: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, StartDateTime, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name from Event where WhoId =: currentRecordId]) {
                wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(b, 'Termin'));
            }          
            for(ContentDocumentLink d: [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.Createdby.Name, ContentDocument.FileExtension FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: currentRecordId AND ContentDocument.FileExtension = 'snote']) {
                wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(d, 'Notiz'));
            }
            for(ContentDocumentLink d: [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.Createdby.Name, ContentDocument.FileExtension FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: currentRecordId AND ContentDocument.FileExtension <> 'snote']) {
                wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(d, 'Datei'));
            }            
            wrapperList.sort();
        }
    }
    
    public class Wrapper implements Comparable {
        
        private final String objectLabel;
        private final Id id;
        private final String subject;
        private final DateTime createDate;
        private final String Ersteller;
        private final String Typ;
        private final String Status;
        
        public wrapper(Task t, String oName) { 
            objectLabel     = oName;
            id              = t.Id;
            subject         = t.Subject;
            createDate      = t.CreatedDate;
            Ersteller       = t.Owner.Name;
            Typ             = t.RecordType.Name;
            Status          = t.Status;
        }
        
        public wrapper(Event e, String oName) {
            objectLabel     = oName;
            id              = e.Id;
            subject         = e.Subject;
            createDate      = e.StartDateTime;
            Ersteller       = e.Owner.Name;
        }
        
        public wrapper(ContentDocumentLink f, String oName) {
            objectLabel     = oName;
            id              = f.ContentDocumentId;
            subject         = f.ContentDocument.Title;
            createDate      = f.ContentDocument.CreatedDate;
            Ersteller       = f.ContentDocument.CreatedBy.Name;
            Typ             = f.ContentDocument.FileExtension;
        }
        
        public Id getId() {
            return id;
        }
        
        public String getSubject() {
            return subject;
        }
        
        public String getTyp() {
            return Typ;
        }    
        
        public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
            return createDate;
        }
        
        public String getObjectLabel() {
            return objectLabel;
        }      

        public String getErsteller() {
            return Ersteller;
        }         

        public String getStatus() {
            return Status;
        }         
        
        // Sort in ascending order
        public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            Wrapper compareToActivity = (Wrapper) compareTo;
            DateTime compareToCreateDate = compareToActivity.getCreatedDate();
            if (createDate > compareToCreateDate) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (createDate < compareToCreateDate) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There are 2 ways you can go about it.

One option is to mark your wrapper class properties as `@AuraEnabled` and make them public.

```
public class Wrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String objectLabel;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String id;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String subject;

    @AuraEnabled
    public DateTime createDate;
}
```

You can then directly bind the list from Apex to the `data` attribute of `lightning-datatable`.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getWrapperData from '@salesforce/apex/DokuBox_6.getWrapperData';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'objectLabel' },
    { label: 'Subject', fieldName: 'subject', type: 'string' },
    { label: 'Created Date', fieldName: 'createDate', type: 'date' },
];

export default class Datatabledemo extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    data = [];
    columns = columns;

    @wire(getWrapperData, {currentRecordId: '$recordId'})
    dataFn({data}){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={data}
            columns={columns}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

If you dont want to make your wrapper class properties public, you can serialize the list and send it to your component.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String getWrapperData(String currentRecordId) {
    List<Wrapper> wrapperList = new List<Wrapper>();
    for(Task a: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status from Task where WhoId =: currentRecordId AND Subject LIKE 'E-Mail:%']) {
        wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(a, 'E-Mail'));
    }
    for(Task a: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name, RecordType.Name, Status from Task where WhoId =: currentRecordId AND (NOT Subject LIKE 'E-Mail:%')]) {
        wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(a, 'Aufgabe'));
    }            
    for(Event b: [select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, StartDateTime, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name from Event where WhoId =: currentRecordId]) {
        wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(b, 'Termin'));
    }          
    for(ContentDocumentLink d: [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.Createdby.Name, ContentDocument.FileExtension FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: currentRecordId AND ContentDocument.FileExtension = 'snote']) {
        wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(d, 'Notiz'));
    }
    for(ContentDocumentLink d: [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.Createdby.Name, ContentDocument.FileExtension FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: currentRecordId AND ContentDocument.FileExtension <> 'snote']) {
        wrapperList.add(new Wrapper(d, 'Datei'));
    }            
    wrapperList.sort();          
            
    return JSON.serialize(wrapperList);
}
```

Inside your component, you just need to convert the String back to JSON, using `JSON.parse`.

```
@wire(getWrapperData)
dataFn({data}){
    if(data){
        this.data = JSON.parse(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, than I have to create a lightning component and component controller or should I add the code to the visualfoce page? At the moment I display the datatable on a visualforce page. Sorry, but I'm not realy familiar with lightning components.

Comment: Ideally, you should create a component to keep things modular, but you can directly embed a datatable too. (Theoretically... I havent tried that though. As long as you are able to pass the data that the datatable needs, you should be good.)

Comment: component would be great, but I'm not familiar with this kind of code. Could you give some code for the component and the component controller?

Comment: I just updated the answer with those snippets - the second and third code snippets are the component's controller and component. The third snippet is a new Apex method that you have to add to your class. Finally, replace the dataFn from the second code snippet with the 4th one (basically just adding JSON.parse)

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand the whole construction. If my apex with the code from the 4th snippet I have no more items to return. Sorry but this is new for me.